# string/char * reallocation exception

Tags: c, string, char, realloc

I've been asked to create a function that takes a string and add it to another string with '#' between every word and with '@' at the end without any spaces in the end.
I've written this code but it seen to not work , can you help me ?
there is an exception in the reallocation line, I believe its because of the '\0' in the end or some like the, but I dont know how to fix that.

```
void addStr(char* addTo, char* str,int on)
{
    //on ==1 for nun last string to add
    if (str != NULL) {
        while (str != NULL)
        {
            char* temp = strtok(str, " \0\n");
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                addTo = (char*)realloc(addTo, strlen(addTo) + strlen(temp) * sizeof(char) + 1);
                strcat(addTo, temp);
                if (str != NULL)
                    strcat(addTo, "#");
            }
        }
        if(on)
            strcat(addTo, "@");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many problems, but the most obvious one is the signature of your function. Do look at the signature of `realloc`. Does it look like `void realloc(void*, size_t)`? Nope, it is `void* realloc(void*, size_t)`. Can you think of a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Reallocating memory passed to a function with a single level of indirection is tricky because in doing so you will invalidate the address held by the calling context. To do this properly you either need to return the new address with the expectation the caller reassigns this in the event of success, or use a second level of indirection to alter the callers context directly.

The two signatures for these functions would be:

```
char *addTo(char *, char *, int);
/* or */
void addTo(char **, char *, int);
```

As for the loop itself, you are not using the `strtok` interface correctly. Subsequent calls to the function should pass `NULL` as the first argument in order to continue tokenizing the original string. Otherwise, you'll continue to loop forever as `strtok` will repeatedly return the first token.

Additionally, you must ensure your buffer always has enough room for the NUL terminating byte (`'\0'`) that marks a valid C string. In this case, the size of the buffer is the length of the existing string, plus the length of the token, plus the size of one character (`'#'` or `'@'`), plus one for the NUL byte.

Note that `sizeof (char)` is *guaranteed* to be `1`. Its inclusion is redundant and error prone.

Here's an example program using the second signature mentioned earlier. We *could* get more clever with the allocation of memory here to potentially save a byte in the event that `tail` is false (or the string contains a single token), but I'm not going to for this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SEP " \n"
void edit_string(char **dest, char *src, int tail) {
    char *tok = strtok(src, SEP);

    while (tok) {
        char *resized = realloc(*dest, strlen(*dest) + strlen(tok) + 2);

        if (!resized)
            /* handle failure */;

        strcat(resized, tok);

        if ((tok = strtok(NULL, SEP)))
            strcat(resized, "#");

        *dest = resized;
    }

    if (tail)
        strcat(*dest, "@");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *dest = calloc(1, 1);
    char input[] = "hello world";

    edit_string(&dest, input, argc > 1);

    printf("%s\n", dest);
    free(dest);
}
```